# displaying a crystal pdf in an ASP web application using Chrome

Tags: .net, google-chrome, crystal-reports

I am using win xp, vs2008, adobe 10, and the latest version of Chrome.

When I try to bring up a crystal report in pdf mode using Chrome, nothing comes up.
I have tried setting the chrome plugins to enabling adobe and disabling the chrome pdf reader, but I am still not getting anything.

On my crystal viewer webpage I have set the print mode to pdf. This works fine in IE but it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Crystal Reports you are using? In Crystal Reports 2005, it is a bug in Crystal Reports Viewer control. You can search for [Crystal Reports Service Packs](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/service_packs/crystal_reports_en.asp) and install them.

You need to enable Popups in Google Chrome also.